# javafaker - cannot generate UK postcodes due to error

Tags: java, katalon-studio, faker

I'm trying to use Faker to generate postcodes in Katalon. I have imported javafaker jar to the project drivers folder. The following code gives me an error and I cannot work out why:

```java
import com.github.javafaker.Faker
Faker faker = new Faker(Locale.UK)
String post = faker.address.zipCode()
println(post)
```

I get:

```plaintext
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve #{regexify '[A-PR-UWYZ]([A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]?|[0-9][ABCDEFGHJKPSTUW0-9]?) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}'} directive.
    at com.github.javafaker.service.FakeValuesService.resolveExpression(FakeValuesService.java:382)
    at com.github.javafaker.service.FakeValuesService.resolve(FakeValuesService.java:337)
    at com.github.javafaker.Address.zipCode(Address.java:35)
    at com.github.javafaker.Address$zipCode$1.call(Unknown Source)
```

- I have set the `Locale` value as `UK` (united kingdom). If I try other locales, I get postcodes in (presumably) that format but no errors thrown.
- I have also tried:
  `Faker faker = new Faker(new Locale("en-GB"))` (slightly different GB version, same error).
- I have not tried this outside of Katalon but others have had success with different values.
- I have also tried three different versions of the jar.

Any help appreciated! Thanks Dan

Comment: Looks like there's something missing (maybe some parsing component). You should use Maven to add the library to your project (see its [Usage section](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker#usage)): it will ensure any dependency is correctly added too.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Katalon Studio so there is no dependency manager for external libraries but I was able to track down additional dependencies from the maven site and manually add jars to my project (I added three in total if anyone is interested! These are: automaton-1.11-8.jar, generex-1.0.2.jar, javafaker-1.0.2.jar).

Answer (score 0):

Because en-GB.yml file is not having data for zipcode. They have complete data for US in file en-US.yml, but not for UK.